# Rails 2, redmine 1.1.1, gem whenever, how to execute code from a plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, whenever, redmine-plugins

im having a problem using the gem whenever v0.8.4. The `config/schedule.rb` looks like this:

```
every :day, :at => '8am' do
  runner "TimeclockReportSender.sendReports"
end
```

The thing is the `TimeclockReportSender.sendReports` code does not execute. The file is in `/vendor/plugins/plugin_name/lib/reports/timeclock_report.rb`.

Im developing at a rails 2.3.5 project, using redmine 1.1.1. Any one knows how i can specify the whenever to execute the plugin module code or if i must put this piece of code elsewhere.

### UPDATE

```
module TimeclockReportSender
    require "reports/timeclock_report.rb"
    #verify and send every report that has date_to_send == today
    def self.sendReports
        reports = CtTimeclockReport.find(:all)
        reports.each do |rpt|
            if !rpt.date_to_send.nil?
                if rpt.date_to_send.to_date() == Date.today
                    users = CtTimeclockReport.getAllUsersFromReport(rpt)
                    period = CtSettingsPeriod.getPeriod(rpt.ct_settings_period_id)
                    project = Project.find(period.project_id)
                    pdf = TimeclockReport.createAndGetReport(rpt,project)
                    sent = TimeclockReportSender.sendReport(rpt,pdf,users)
                    TimeclockReportSender.updateReportDate(rpt)
                end
            end
        end
    end

#send a single report pdf via email to the users list
def self.sendReport(report,pdfReport,users)
    #send the report to each user
    users.each do |usr|
        usr = User.find(usr.user_id)
        if !usr.nil?
            CtMailer.deliver_reportEmail(report,pdfReport,usr)
        end
    end
    return true
end
```

when i run the command:
`script/runner -e production '\''TimeclockReportSender.sendReports'\'''` at rails root, it ask`s me some input ... this command it`s the crontab generated from whenever

### UPDATE2

To run the sendReports method, i must require the file in my controller using

   `require "reports/timeclock_report_sender.rb"`

### FIXED

I ran the cmd from cron and found out that rails was not finding my module. The solution was to put the code inside a Model from my plugin, than it found his code. Thanks 4 all :D

Comment: use 4 spaces before each line of code on blocks of code.  You can read more about SO markdown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Also you can use `'s to show inline code.

Comment: Can we see where `sendReports` is defined?  Can you confirm you can call `sendReports` on `TimeclockReportSender`

Comment: @toolz, sendReports is defined inside the timeclock_report.rb file, it look`s like this:

`module TimeclockReportSender    
  def self.sendReports    
  end
end`
I can call `TimeclockReportSender.sendReports` in one of my controllers from my plugin and it works fine. The crontab file looks like this:
`# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: ct
0 8 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/redmine-1.1.1 && script/runner -e production '\''TimeclockReportSender.sendReports'\'''
`

Comment: You need to help me help you!  Edit your original question and post time_clock_report_sender.rb.  I don't even know what I'm necessarily looking for, but possibly your method is private or protected and thus runner can't access it.

Comment: oh ok!, sorry this is my first time using stack overflow

Comment: What is the _exact_ error you get when you run the command manually?

Comment: You should make your solution into an answer

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I found out that the reason why it was not executing by running the cmd from cron and then i found out that rails was not finding my module.

The solution was to put the code inside a Model from my plugin, than cron found his code. Thanks for the help guys.